# How to get in json a column that combine from two field in sql?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have table with those columns in mssql:

```
 id, name, surname, age
```

How to combine `name` and `surname` into `info` when I get json from the sql:

```
select id, name, surname, age from table for json auto
```

What I get is:

```
[{ id, name, surname, age }]
```

And what I need is:

```
[{ id, info: { name, surname }, age }]
```

This is possible to do with mssql? if so, how can I do it in sql?

Comment: `'[{ id, info: { name, surname }, age }]'` isn't valid JSON. Neither is `'[{ id, name, surname, age }]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `FOR JSON PATH` to build the nested ouptut:

```
SELECT 
   id, 
   name AS 'info.name', 
   surname AS 'info.surname', 
   age 
FROM (VALUES
   (1, 'Name', 'Surname', 35)  
) t (id, name, surname, age)
FOR JSON PATH
```

Result:

```
[{"id":1,"info":{"name":"Name","surname":"Surname"},"age":35}]
```

Comment: the problem is when I use JSON PATH and i have left join in the query, it's not work. there is a way to solve this with left join?

Comment: I think, yes, @JonSud, but you need to post sample data and your current statement. Or you can make your current statement a subquery and use `FOR JSON PATH` using the statement from the answer.